# QWidget and QML Property Bindings

Tags: qt, qml

How can I use [property bindings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/propertybinding.html) in conjunction with "classic" Qt widgets? Seems to be a cool feature, more powerful than Cocoa Bindings but unfortunately it appears to be restricted to QML.

I did not found any documentation about how to set up these bindings in QtDesigner or programmatically using C++/Python.

Comment: Property bindings are a feature of QML, they're not something you can access without it.  I believe in Qt 5 it is intended that you will be able to use QML to build widget-based UIs, but for now they're not available.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental Qt project called "Qt Quick Components for Desktop".

It encapsulated traditional widgets into QML components, so that you can design in QML a traditional widget based UI, including goodies like property binding (and styles !)

see http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/